# How do you install newest version of node.js on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to install the latest stable version of Node.js on Raspberry Pi 3.  How do I do it in such a way that a) I'm always able to update to latest LTS version b) Can easily switch between versions

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are after the very latest versions of node.js, you will need to either build/test your own binaries for the specific CPU and OS target in your Raspberry Pi 3 or you will want to find an already built binary which may not be the absolute latest version.

Comment: Thanks. Updated Q to indicate latest LTS. Don't need bleeding edge / master.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [Node version manager](https://github.com/tj/n) works great, even for ARM based processors (like Raspberry Pi).

You need to remove the existing version of node installed on Raspbian however (if you are using this distro):

Remove old:

```
sudo -i
apt-get remove nodered -y
apt-get remove nodejs nodejs-legacy -y
exit
```

Install n (it will also install latest stable Node.js):

`curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash`

Verify:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ node --version
nv7.6.0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm --version
4.1.2
```

Comment: This seems to install Node only for the Pi user.

Answer (score 3):

If you've installed nvm, you can use `nvm install latest` or `nvm install stable`.

That's the best way to keep it up-to-date. You could write a bash script to handle keeping your Node.js version in sync with the latest using nvm.